# which one is the better solution for accessibillity? aria hidden, remove the element from DOM or something else

Tags: javascript, accessibility, wai-aria

Personally, I think remove element could be better for website maintaining, but is it save to do so for accessibility?

The sample would be

```
      <input type="radio" value="single" name="userGroup" id="single" required />
      <label for="single">Single</label>

      <input type="radio" value="families" class="form-checkbox" name="userGroup" id="families" required />
      <label for="families" >Families</label>
```

The rest of form fields will be different based on the userGroup

When user toggle between single and families, the families group will have extra fields like 'bill payment' section (combined or not) and 'how you would like to share your data plan' (limited usage or not) on top of single form fields

As a form, should elements like 'bill payment' be aria-hidden true or removed from DOM?

Comment: If element isn't needed and doesn't exist why would there be any issues? Sounds like you are over thinking this. No idea what sample is supposed to show us either

Comment: good point i will update the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is hard to answer this without a lot more context and/or a URL to see it in action.

If you allow the user to go back and change the selection, and that then changes the subsequent fields, then consider when a user makes a mistake. By removing the fields from the DOM completely, then anything the user already typed is lost. If it was a mistake, then the user toggles back and sees the lost information and probably gets annoyed.

Strictly from an accessibility perspective I would only hide the fields so a user can toggle between Single and Families and not lose any information he/she maybe struggled to enter.

You can also probably skip using `aria-hidden` if you use CSS to set the container to `display:none` as that will also hide it from screen readers. This means you will not have to manage both CSS and HTML attributes when toggled, you can just manage one of them.

Comment: Good stuff, particularly the bit about mistakes.

Comment: Can't believe there is not yet a word coined for the fury one feels when a web form resets.

Comment: Because a guttural shout has no letters. Just spittle.